# cufftcomplex.h Programmers reference/Documentation

Tags: c, cuda, cufft

I am working on an cufft implementation and can't find any reference to the cufftcomplex functions. I found cucomplex.h through google, though, but that doesn't help me. Specifically i want to know, how to read out the imaginary part and the real part of the cufftcomplex struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types `cufftComplex` and `cuComplex` are actually same. It is documented in the [cuFFT documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/#cufft-types-others). In `cufft.h` you will find the typedef:

```
typedef cuComplex cufftComplex;
```

In `cuComplex.h` you will find that `cuComplex` is indeed a `float2`, i.e. you can read out the real value with `c.x` and the imaginary value with `c.y`. Or better use the functions `cuCrealf()` and `cuCimagf()` which are provided in `cuComplex.h`.